# How to Drag field from radlistbox/radtreeview to radgrid header

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radgrid, radtreeview, telerik-radlistbox

I'm beginners in telerik
I have columns name in a Rad List.
I want to show columns in RadGrid by dragging columns name from radlist to RadGrid.
And also i want to remove columns from radgrid by dragging out column name from radgrid to radlist.[image: drop field in radgrid]

Double click on field in list/tree will also add to grid header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string type list in code behind for drag drop columns. When drag a string add it into list and then bind the radgrid from that list

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this problem.
 I thing drag drop is possible on rows only in Radgrid